# Deriving Maximum Likelihood Estimators for a Linear Model with Exponential Error Term

Tags: exponential-function, maximum-likelihood, linear-regression

I am currently working on a problem where I need to derive the maximum likelihood estimators for a linear model with an exponential error term. Here's the problem:

> A machine sequentially performs two tasks. The first task requires an unobservable exponentially distributed amount of time $\epsilon$, with unknown mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. The second task requires an amount of time, proportional to an observable positive-valued variable
> $x$ which is independent of $\epsilon$; the proportionality constant is positive, but otherwise unknown, and can be represented by $\beta$. The total time y required to process a single job is the sum of the times it takes to complete the two tasks.

Given the problem, I've been tasked with:

1. Writing down a linear statistical model relating $y$ to $x$.
2. Deriving maximum likelihood estimators for $\beta$ and $\lambda$.

For the first part, I believe the model would be
$y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon$ is the error term. For the second part I estimated value of lambda:

$L(\lambda, \beta) = \prod_{i=1}^n ( \lambda e^{-\lambda (y_i - \beta x_i)}$

$L(\lambda, \beta) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda \sum (y_i - \beta x_i)}$

$\ln(L(\lambda)) = n \ln(\lambda) - \lambda \sum (y_i - \beta x_i)$

$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \beta x_i)}$

But I don't know how to estimate value for beta:

$\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)=0$

Which doesn't make sense to me.
Any help on how to tackle the estimation for β or insights into the problem would be greatly appreciated!